# Dojo FilteringSelect - Full JSON Response Data Not Visible

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

Trying to convert a jQuery autocomplete to a Dojo version.  Initally followed this advice ([Textbox autocomplete with DOJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871110/textbox-autocomplete-with-dojo)), but switched to `JsonRest`.

When entering input (eg. "th") i can see the proper JSON response in the console, `[{"id":"thing1","label":"thing1"},{"id":"thing2","label":"thing2"},{"id":"thing3","label":"thing3"}]`, but no list of options appears on screen.  When the focus leaves the target `input`, it's always autocompleted with the first element ("thing1" in this example).

```
// DOM Element
<div id="things"></div>

// Get data
var jsonStore = new JsonRest  ({  
    target: "/ajax_suggest/autocomplete"
});

// Autocomplete attempt
ready(function(){

    var thingSearch = new FilteringSelect({
        id: "things",
        name: "things",
        store: jsonStore,
        placeHolder: "Search the things...",
        searchAttr: "term",
        onSearch: function(results, query) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        }                   
    },"things");

    thingSearch.startup();

});
```

So, at this point, i'm satisfied that the data is arriving correctly after the `input` data has been processed, and ultimately, the contents of the `input` are "autocompleted", but i'm missing something, or haven't grasped something, pretty fundamental here to get the full response to be displayed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `searchAttr: "term"`, but "term" is not in your JsonRest store - I think you want that to be `searchAttr: "label"`

Comment: Aha!  Thanks, @GavinR!  I wasn't sure what you were on about initially, as my understanding of `searchAttr` was that it set the name of the GET variable for my processing script (ie. my script expected "term", and so it didn't want to be "label").  I happened across a section from the Reference Guide (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#custom-displayed-value-search-text) which triggered a lightbulb moment and then i understood what you meant. Changing the store to `[{"id":"thing1","term":"thing1"}...` and lo and behold it worked.